# Is there a way to run a Excel Macro on multiple worksheets to grab select range images and save them locally

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with 6 worksheets. One Worksheet holds the data and the remaining 5 have graphs created using the data worksheet. I'm looking to grab an image of the chart on each worksheet and save it on my webserver location, such that I can use that image on my website. However, I'm able to do it successfully only on the active sheet, but no luck when I try to specify a sheet name and range.

In the past, I did grab images from Excel but only from active sheets, as shown below.

```
Sub MakePicture()

    Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = Range("A1:G6")
    ''' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard

    rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    ''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .Name = "Table"
    .Activate
    End With

    ''' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete the chart.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Table").Chart.Export Filename:="C:\SavedRange.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Table").Delete
    Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

The expected result is to grab 5 images from 5 worksheets and save them in the library.

Comment: hi, u can use a " For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets" to cycle all sheets, and inside your code. u just have to change the activesheet to ws. good luck

Comment: Have you thought about using a png rather than jpg?  `.Export Filename:="C:\SavedRange" & ws & ".png", Filtername:="PNG"`, where ws is your worksheet number when looping.  Lossless compression (png) versus lossy (jpeg).  [Always a fun image to show this difference](http://img.labnol.org/di/jpg_vs_png.png).

Comment: Hi, Yes I do use .png formats to save images as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
Sub MakePicture()
Dim rgExp As Range 
Dim WS As Worksheet
''' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard

rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied

For each WS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set rgExp = WS.Range("A1:G6")
    With WS.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .Name = "Table"
    .Activate
End With

''' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete chart.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveChart.Paste
    WS.ChartObjects("Table").Chart.Export Filename:="C:\SavedRange.jpeg", Filtername:="JPEG"
    WS.ChartObjects("Table").Delete
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for sharing. I just tried to implement this and it still gives me one blank image output at end.

Comment: @Hiranya Are you able to share the error you are getting?

Comment: @Hiranya I updated my answer maybe I think it needs to be .jpeg instead of .jpg

Comment: Thank you. jpeg worked. but can you please guide me how to implement this. right now when I add this macro, its only saving one image from data sheet. is there a way to input sheet name and pick a range and add separate file names for each image grab from worksheet ?

Comment: @Hiranya How is your data in the worksheets? Is it in different locations? or is it in the same? I did modify so bits can you try and see?